# Mann-Whitney U Test test valid for percentages (% seagrass cover)?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, zero-inflation, percentage

Is the Mann-Whitney U Test  test valid for percentages (not counts, but percent cover of seagrass)? All my data points are ***average*** percent cover of seagrass with about 53% of the data being zeros across 8 group levels/columns (4 years x 2 seasons per year).

I'd like to test the null hypothesis that there is no statistical difference in median seagrass cover between "dry" and "wet" seasons, for each year.

Each value is the average of 10 randomly chosen, independent, observations per site (n=47 sites). I'm working in R.

I thought beta regression would work, but learned values can't equal 0 or 1, logistic regression is only for success/failure type data, and my data have unequal variance so I can't do any parametric tests.

```
years <- seq(2008:2011)
season <- c("dry", "wet")
site <- seq(1:47)
percent range between 0.0 (0%) to 0.85 (85%)

Site   2008_dry   2008_wet   2009_dry  etc...
1      0          0          
2      0.10       0.26
3      0          0.71
4      0.52       0
etc...
```

Comment: "*I thought beta regression would work, but learned values can't equal 0 or 1*" - hence the existence of 0-inflated, 1-inflated and 0-and-1 inflated beta regression 2. "my data have unequal variance so I can't do any parametric tests" -- I can't fathom the reasoning here at all. A test based on such an inflated-beta regression would be a *parametric test*, for example, without requiring equal variances. 3. If you have covariates (otherwise why consider beta regression or logistic regression?) ... Mann-Whitney won't do.

Comment: Didn’t know beta regression was a parametric test, I only remember being taught about the usual suspects (t-test, ANOVA, etc.). Thanks!

Comment: Oddly enough, I found the "perfect" example here, in case anyone is interested: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309047/zero-inflated-beta-regression-using-gamlss-for-vegetation-cover-data

Comment: On the meaning of "parametric" among statisticians; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics ... this usage is based on its usual meaning in mathematics and the specific use in statistics seems to originate with Fisher nearly a century ago (though I expect that in conversations it likely occurred years earlier). I'd correct the first sentence there slightly but it's fine for a first approximation.